# JavaScript global object?

Tags: javascript

Does the value of "this" refer to the global object or the object "o" in the program below?

More importantly, what code could I run to test what the reference of "this" is?

```
function F() { 
    function C() { 
        return this;
    } 
    return C();
} 

var o = new F();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It refers to the global object (`window`).

*Edit:* Actually, it will refer to both, the global object **and** `o`,  because they are the same. `o` will have a reference to the object returned from `F()` which is the object returned from `C()` which is the `window` object ;)

You can call `console.log(this)` to find out which object it refers to. It should give you a listing of all the methods of the object on the console and you should be able to infer from this which object it is.
For this to work in Firefox, you need Firebug. Don't know for IE.

**Update:**

[@Anurag already showed you how to explicitly set `this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374912/javascript-global-object/5374931#5374931). If you just want to refer to `this` of a higher scope, you have to assign it to a variable explicitly. Example:

```
function F() {
    var that = this; 
    function C() { 
        console.log(that);
    } 
    C();
}
```

Comment: I thought that since "this" is within the function F(), and since function f() is assigned to object 0, then it would have maybe referred to object O, in a closure-type way.

Comment: @Michael : `this` is always special. You can only refer to `this` of a higher scope by assigning it to another variable. Any function you call like `func()` will have `this` set to the global object.

Answer (score 2):

`this` refers to the global object in your program. To get `this` to reference the instance of `F`, try,

```
function F() { 
    function C() { 
        return this;
    } 
    return C.call(this); // call C with the object of F as a context
} 

var o = new F();
```

On Chrome, you could simply enter the variable to inspect, and its value will get logged. It's similar to doing a `console.log(object)`, but much easier to work with. Here's a screenshot of running this code sample in Chrome. The value of the last statement `o` is automatically printed, and I printed it once again, just to be sure. It logged `DOMWindow` which refers to the global window object on the browser.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. as I told Felix King, I thought that since "this" is within the function F(), and since function f() is assigned to object 0, then it would have maybe referred to object O, in a closure-type way.

Comment: `this` is kinda funky and has a special meaning inside functions, thus it doesn't follow the rules of a closure. You could of-course assign it to a variable with a different name, and then reference that variable inside the function, but not `this`.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answers:

When a function is called, `this` is set depending on how it's called.  If it's called with `myfunc.call` or `myfunc.apply`, then `this` is set to the first passed argument.  If it's called in the 'dotted' form, i.e. `myObject.myfunc()` then `this` is set to whatever is before the dot.

There is an exception to this rule, which is that it's possible to bake the value of `this` in with `bind`, in which case it will be whatever has been bound. i.e. in `var boundfunc = myfunc.bind(myobj);` then any time `boundfunc` is called, it would be like calling `myfunc` but with `this` referring to `myobj` regardless of anything else.  Here's an example that does that:

```
function F() { 
    var C = function() { 
        return this;
    }.bind(this);
    return C();
} 

var o = new F();
```

If none of these cases are applicable, then `this` is always either the global object (`window` if you're in a browser), or, if you're in strict mode it's `undefined`.